# Scroll к элементу

Tags: java, android, прокрутка

У меня есть расписание на экране. Надо, чтобы по нажатию кнопки осуществлялся `ScrollTo()` либо `ScrollBy()` к элементу, но я не знаю, как определять координаты элемента `TextView`. Возможно, это можно осуществить по-другому?

Comment: правильно ли я понял, Вам нужно листать список вверх вниз с помощью скрула?

Comment: И вниз, и вверх нужно листать. Просто меню должна быть фиксированной

Comment: Ну пока можно ограничится только листанием вни\з

Comment: Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста. "Определять координаты элемента TextView" - это определять координаты чего-то внутри одного TextView, или этих TextView у вас несколько?

Comment: Несколько элементов

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял из Ваших комментариев, то для простого скрулинга вверх/вниз в Вашем layout'е просто оберните его в `ScrollView`.

Примерно это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        style="@style/TextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Нет, программно надо листать

Comment: В ScrollView он уже обернут, но надо как-то отлавливать координаты элемента и листать программно к нему